# How do I get BIND (DNS) to be authoritative about a tld for more than a minute

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved, bind9

I tried to block the `.zip` TLD on my laptop (running fedora 38) with bind.

1. Installing bind
2. Updating `named.conf`:

   ```
   options {
       listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
       listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
       directory   "/var/named";
       dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
       statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
       memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
       secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
       recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
       allow-query     { localhost; };

       /* 
       - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
       - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable 
       recursion. 
       - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access 
       control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
       cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification 
       attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
       reduce such attack surface 
       */
       recursion yes;

       forwarders { 8.8.8.8; };

       dnssec-validation yes;

       managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
       geoip-directory "/usr/share/GeoIP";

       pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
       session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

       /* https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy */
       include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";

       /* this makes it block everything */
       // response-policy { zone "zip"; };
   };

   logging {
           channel default_debug {
                   file "data/named.run";
                   severity dynamic;
           };
   };

   zone "zip" IN {
       type master;
       file "zip-rpz";
       allow-update { none; };
   };

   zone "." IN {
       type hint;
       file "named.ca";
   };

   include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
   include "/etc/named.root.key";
   ```
3. Added `/var/named/zip-rpz`:

   ```
   $TTL 1D                ; default expiration time (in seconds) of all RRs without their own TTL value
   @       IN  SOA   ns.zip. postmaster.ns.zip. ( 2020091025 7200 3600 1209600 3600 )
   @       IN      NS      ns1                    ; nameserver
   *       IN      A       127.0.0.1              ; localhost
           IN      AAAA    ::                     ; localhost
   ```
4. Apply temporarily

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl enable named
   sudo service named restart
   resolvectl dns wlp0s20f3 127.0.0.1
   ```

However, running `dig url.zip` returns 127.0.0.1 only for the next minute or so – after that it shows the "correct" ip (and I can visit the site in the Browser again).
Why is it getting reset?

If I remove the `forwarders` line, same result.

If I set `recursion no;`, I am unable to resolve anything *other* than .zip urls (those point to 127.0.0.1)

Comment: @roaima after that it resolves the name "correctly" again; i.e. to an IP which is actually associated with the domain, and I can visit it in the browser and such. As if I didn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it?

If I’m not mistaken, the problem seems to be with `systemd-resolve` / `resolvectl` not persisting it’s settings for long...

If I change the file `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` such that it contains

```
...
[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.1
...
```

And then reboot, it seems to do (finally) what it should.

---

I’d still like to know why then apparantly

```bash
resolvectl dns wlp0s20f3 127.0.0.1
```

only takes effect so briefly

Comment: Your wireless access point might be using DHCP with very short lease lifetime, so the DHCP client needs to update the lease (and refresh the network parameters received from the AP's DHCP server, including the DNS server addresses) once per minute.